# jquery inside javascript function to hide div array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am using jquery inside the javascript function to hide & show div.
I need to show only div "Area" while hide other div

This one works, when i directly put the name of the div to hide & show  :---

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>

function area_visible()
{


  $('.Area').show();
  $('.Area-1').hide();
  $('.Area-2').hide();
  $('.Area-3').hide();


}
```

This one does not works if i try to access using array of div class, even alert message is not displayed 4 times for loop :----

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>

var area_id = [
    "Area" , "Area-1", "Area-2", "Area-3"
];



function area_visible()
{

  $(area_id).each(function(index, element) {
        if(element != area_id[0] )
        {
          $("#" + element).hide();
        }
      alert('11');
    });


}
```

Please suggest. How to hide and show div by taking there name from an array (and i want to use jquery inside javascript function) ?

Comment: you have not called your function anywhere.

Comment: in the first example you are addressing them as classes, and in the second you are addressing them as though they are element IDs. Which are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$("#" + element).hide();
```

to

```
$("." + element).hide();
```

You are trying to target an ID you must use `.` to target class.

Comment: I saw the first answer and was thoroughly confused :p

Comment: @RGraham haha i confused myself for a second there too so i deleted it for a second ^^

Answer (score 1):

in your first function you are using class `$('.Area-1')` and the second function you are selecting with ID `$("#"+element)`

so the fix is easy just change '#' to '.' in the second function

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your id selector to a class selector and initiate the function:

```
$("." + element).hide(); // for your second function.
```

and initialize your func:

```
area_visible(); // for both it will work.
```